# Strip from .HTML file all up to [stringxyz]

Tags: html, regex

1. I have HTML files containing a table.
2. I would like to strip only the table out of the files.
3. I don't know regex very well and can't figure out how to Find/Replace everything up to [stringxyz] (which will leave the footer but I figure I can strip that later).
4. I've tried [\s\S] but it does not seem to work in TextCrawler3.

Thanks in advance for all suggestions (including different strategies).

Comment: So is not here to write code for you. Find a solution and, if it doesn't work, then supply that code and we'll help you.

Comment: @Rob   I think that is a little unfair as a response.  I did not ask anyone to write code and specifically requested suggestions of different (better) STRATEGIES to get the results I seek.  To me (admittedly a newbie here) that is better than posting literally a large amount of code and hoping someone will wade through it.

Comment: The only way to do that would be to write code for you or link to other sites. Both are not allowed on SO. In addition, the question asks for suggestions which would be opinions and open ended. Also not allowed. This is not the right platform for what you are asking. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

**Current input:**

```
<b><i>some text and tag
is hare</i></b>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            it is a row
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>some text else is here</p>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<b><i>some text and tag
is hare</i></b> 
<p>some text else is here</p>
```

If yes, try this:

```
/<table>[\s\S]+<\/table>/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aU2eX7/4)

Comment: Thanks for the reply -- and for the link to the Regex Demo site.  I will play with it there but per your Current Input the Expected Output I seek is the opposite of yours.  Specifically this is what I hope to yield:

<table>
       <tr>
             <td> it is a row <td>
       </tr>
</table>

Comment: @MikeShields Ok, what language are you using? JavaScript?

Comment: I'm not using a language --  I had hoped to do this via a Text Program but it does not seem possible via Notepad++ or TextCrawlerPro.

Comment: Ok, try [`/(<table>[\s\S]+<\/table>)/`](https://regex101.com/r/lT2gT8/1) pattern, Now `$1` is containing what you need

Comment: A million thanks -- finally got your last code to work in Notepad ++

Comment: Glad I could help.